# IBM Websphere application server jdbc Connection pool performance issue

Tags: jdbc, db2, websphere

I am using IBM WAS 8.5 on a windows server
the database I am working with, is DB2 9.7 and is installed on windows server too (on another machine).

I have a table for logs that contains more than 4,000,000 records.
the data is growing very fast.

when I run a count query on that table, the result is very confusing.
with WAS jdbc connection pool, the count take more than 10 seconds to get the result,
but with a simple jdbc connection (in the same application or out of it using any db tool) the result is gaind in less than 0.2 seconds!

I've tried jmeter to perform load test and tivoli to find the right setting but no result!

I've tried dbpool too, the result was better but not acceptable!
any idea?!

Comment: Can you measure the time it needs to get connection from datasource(or even click on test connection if it takes 10 sec) and the time to proceed the query?

There are lot of possible bottlenecks - overall WebSphere JVM performance, network, drivers, number of connections in pool, DB response time etc.

Comment: the test connection is working normally, in fact all the connections are working normally. just this select on the table with 4milion records is taking very long time

Comment: You might try the WebSphere forum: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000266

Answer (score 0):

I would start with http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247168 and open a PMR if you are unable to analyze the data.  This can be any number of problems and without data very difficult to hazard a guess.

Also, are you doing the necessary DB2 work on the DB2 side with runstats/reorg?

Do you have Wireshark and are you looking at the TCP between the app server and the database?  Are you seeing any lag there or not?

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the link you've put there, does not provide any thing about the response time and the performance. my problem is that the same query in the same application with direct JDBC is working fine, but with WAS connection pool is very slow. the this is not a db2 issue or TCP issue.